# Is a certain map $\mathbb{R}\to \widehat{\mathbb{R}}$ a homeomorphism?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

I'm studying harmonic analysis, and I'm trying to understand the fact that
$$\phi: \mathbb{R}\to \widehat{\mathbb{R}}: s \mapsto (t \mapsto \exp(2\pi i st))$$
is an isomorphism of topological groups (here we consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a topological group for the usual topology and the usual addition $+$).

So far, I have managed to show that $\phi$ is a group isomorphism (surjectivity was the harder part). It remains to show that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, i.e. that both $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are continuous.

To show continuity of $\phi$, we need to show that if $\{s_\lambda\}$ is a net that converges to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then $$\exp(2\pi i s_\lambda t) \to 1$$
uniformly in $t\in K$ where $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact. I think I can prove this using the fact that continuous functions are uniformly continuous on compact subsets.

Conversely, I also struggle to show that if $\exp(2\pi i s_\lambda t) \to 1$ uniformly on compact subsets, then $s_\lambda \to 0$. I guess we need some form of complex logarithm for this?

Thanks in advance for any hints/suggestions!

Comment: Define $\hat{\Bbb R}$

Comment: @FShrike Sure, it is the set of continuous group homomorphisms $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{T}$ endowed with the topology of compact convergence. This is tagged with harmonic analysis though, and it is pretty standard notation for the dual group.

Comment: I don't study the subject, is why I ask :) By "compact convergence" do you mean the compact-open topology?

Comment: @FShrike Uhm, a of functions $f_\lambda$ converges to $f$ in the topology of compact convergence if the convergence is uniform on every compact subset of the domain. It turns out that this topology coincides with the compact-open topology in this case.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the information you gave in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\phi(s_\lambda) \to 1$ uniformly on compact subsets. Assume to the contrary that $s_\lambda \not\to 0$. Then there is a subnet $\{s_\mu\}$ and $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|s_\mu| \ge \epsilon$ for all $\mu$. By passing to a further subnet, we may assume that $s_\mu$ has the same sign for all $\mu$. By possibly replacing $\{s_\lambda\}$ by $\{-s_\lambda\}$, we may assume that $s_\mu \ge 0$ for all $\mu$, so that $s_\mu \ge \epsilon$ for all $\mu$.

By assumption, there is an index $\mu$ such that
$$\sup_{t \in [0,\epsilon^{-1}]}|\exp(2\pi is_\mu t)-1| < 1.$$
However, $s_\mu [0, \epsilon^{-1}] = [0, s_\mu \epsilon^{-1}] \supseteq [0,1]$
so that
$$2=\sup_{v \in [0,1]} |\exp(2\pi iv)-1| \le \sup_{t \in [0,\epsilon^{-1}]}| \exp(2\pi i s_\mu t)-1| < 1$$
a contradiction. Hence, $s_\lambda \to 0$, and this is enough to show that the group homomorphism $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous.